# Joining two words to make a single word

Tags: word-choice, compound-adjectives, compound-words, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

I am international engineering student studying in US. I have a question regarding words that are created as a result of joining two words. Usually this happens when two technologies or methodologies are used to create something unique (I am particularly interested in fusion of two words based on abstract ideas or technology). The confusion I have currently is "How to decide the proper word fusion?"

For example: Testbed vs test bed, feedforward vs feed forward vs feed-forward, etc.

I have this confusion because certain authors use certain fusion words. I would like to know if there is a universal rule or any guidance when I have to combine two words indicating abstract concepts.

Comment: Sadly, no. Some words are always written open (_test bed_), some are always written hyphenated (_test-bed_), some are always written closed (_testbed_)—and a lot are written in two or even all three ways, depending on whom you ask. It’s a mess. You just have to use what seems most common in the context you’re using it.

Comment: Perhaps your best bet is to consult a dictionary to see how it is spelled out. That's what I would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We call the "single words" you're talking about [*compound words*](http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/mechanics/compound-words/).

It sounds like you're torn between creating closed and open compound words. The way to choose is to look at what other people are doing. The English language is always being reshaped by how we use it, so while "living room" might be two words today, who knows what will happen in 10 years!

In technical writing, readability always comes first. Choose whatever you think will make your writing more clear and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

**[Compounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics))** or **composition** is the process of word formation that creates compound [lexemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexeme). That is, in familiar terms, compounding occurs when two or more words are joined to make one longer word.
The meaning of the compound may be similar to or different from the meanings of its components in isolation. The component stems of a compound may be of the same part of speech—as in the case of the English word footpath, composed of the two nouns foot and path—or they may belong to different parts of speech, as in the case of the English word blackbird, composed of the adjective black and the noun bird.

**Formation of compounds**
Compound formation rules vary widely across language types. Compounds can be rather long when translating technical documents from English to some other language, since the lengths of the words are theoretically unlimited, especially in chemical terminology.

**endocentric:**    A+B denotes a special kind of B
*Eg: darkroom, smalltalk*
**exocentric:** A+B denotes a special kind of an unexpressed semantic head
*Eg: skinhead, paleface (head: 'person')*
**copulative:** A+B denotes 'the sum' of what A and B denot
*Eg: bittersweet, sleepwalk*
**appositional:**   A and B provide different descriptions for the same referent
*Eg: actor-director, maidservant*

Comment: The question is about regular compounds, not portmanteaus.

Comment: *feedforward* is a "regular" compound?

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that there is "portmanteau", a piece of luggage that opens into two halves.  This word has been "borrowed" (thanks to Lewis Carroll) to describe a word that is composed of parts of two other words, such as "motel" being derived from "motor hotel".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau