# What are combined words called?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a term for two words combined intact to make another word?
E.g. back yard -> backyard, every day -> everyday, etc.

Comment: so, you are looking the names for back and yard, not for backyard, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining two words to make a single word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257882/joining-two-words-to-make-a-single-word/257883#257883) See also  [English compound](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137760/english-compound)

Comment: They are called "compound words".